# How to resolve Error: Column 1 must be named in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the below-mentioned dataframe in R. While pivoting the datafrme, I'm getting `Error: Column 1 must be named` error.

I need to understand what is this exact error about, and is there anything I'm missing here. Also, Please suggest if there could be some better approach to use the pivot wider.

Dataframe<-

```
structure(list(Batch.x = c("", "AA", "AA", "AA", "BA", "BA", 
"BA", "BA", "BA", "BA", "BA", "BA", "BA", "BA", "BN", 
"BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", "BN", 
"NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", 
"NC", "KJ", "KJ", "KJ", "KJ", "KJ", "KJ", "KJ", "KJ", 
"KJ", "KJ", "UY", "UY", "UY", "UY", "UY", "UY", "UY", 
"UY", "UY", "UY", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", 
"IU", "IU", "IU", "IU", "PK", "PK", "PK", "PK", "PK", 
"PK", "PK", "PK", "PK", "PK", "LD", "LD", "LD", "LD", 
"LD", "LD", "LD", "LD", "LD", "LD", "OF", "OF", "OF", 
"OF", "OF", "OF", "OF", "OF", "OF", "OF", "PE", "PE", 
"PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "PE", "HX", 
"HX", "HX", "HX", "HX", "HX", "HX", "HX", "HX", "HX", 
"ZT", "ZT", "ZT", "ZT", "ZT", "ZT", "ZT", "ZT", "ZT", 
"ZT", "ZZ", "ZZ", "ZZ", "ZZ", "ZZ", "ZZ", "ZZ", "ZZ", 
"ZZ", "ZZ", "XA", "XA", "XA", "XA", "XA", "XA", "XA", 
"XA", "XA", "XA", "PV", "PV", "PV", "PV", "PV", "PV", 
"PV", "PV", "PV", "PV", NA), Batch.y = c("", "AA", 
"HX", "PV", "BA", "BN", "NC", "KJ", "UY", "IU", "PK", 
"LD", "OF", "PE", "BA", "BN", "NC", "KJ", "UY", "IU", 
"PK", "LD", "OF", "PE", "BA", "BN", "NC", "KJ", "UY", 
"IU", "PK", "LD", "OF", "HX", "BA", "BN", "NC", "KJ", 
"UY", "IU", "PK", "LD", "OF", "PE", "BA", "BN", "NC", 
"KJ", "UY", "IU", "PK", "LD", "OF", "PE", "BA", "BN", 
"NC", "KJ", "UY", "IU", "PK", "OF", "PE", "HX", "BA", 
"BN", "NC", "KJ", "UY", "IU", "PK", "LD", "OF", "PE", 
"BA", "BN", "NC", "KJ", "UY", "PK", "LD", "OF", "PE", 
"HX", "BA", "BN", "NC", "KJ", "UY", "IU", "PK", "LD", 
"OF", "PE", "BA", "BN", "KJ", "UY", "IU", "PK", "LD", 
"OF", "PE", "HX", "AA", "BA", "BN", "NC", "KJ", "UY", 
"IU", "PK", "LD", "OF", "BA", "BN", "NC", "KJ", "UY", 
"IU", "PK", "LD", "OF", "PE", "BA", "BN", "NC", "KJ", 
"UY", "IU", "PK", "LD", "OF", "PE", "BA", "BN", "NC", 
"KJ", "UY", "IU", "PK", "LD", "OF", "PE", "AA", "BA", 
"BN", "NC", "KJ", "UY", "IU", "PK", "LD", "PE", NA), 
    N = c(4216L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1484L, 49L, 44L, 49L, 137L, 114L, 
    102L, 7L, 20L, 75L, 49L, 660L, 64L, 13L, 51L, 10L, 44L, 11L, 
    31L, 16L, 44L, 64L, 496L, 4L, 30L, 5L, 22L, 1L, 4L, 62L, 
    49L, 13L, 4L, 355L, 22L, 9L, 47L, 5L, 8L, 29L, 137L, 51L, 
    30L, 22L, 727L, 20L, 63L, 7L, 20L, 24L, 114L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 
    20L, 303L, 20L, 4L, 4L, 29L, 102L, 44L, 22L, 47L, 63L, 20L, 
    612L, 5L, 13L, 25L, 7L, 11L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 69L, 2L, 3L, 
    9L, 20L, 31L, 4L, 8L, 20L, 4L, 13L, 2L, 315L, 11L, 75L, 16L, 
    29L, 24L, 4L, 25L, 3L, 11L, 337L, 18L, 1L, 85L, 98L, 62L, 
    30L, 100L, 29L, 70L, 9L, 24L, 41L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 22L, 7L, 
    38L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 112L, 23L, 15L, 7L, 30L, 28L, 21L, 2L, 24L, 
    11L, 580L, 177L, 130L, 91L, 224L, 108L, 221L, 39L, 63L, 95L, 
    1L, 104L, 122L, 96L, 74L, 104L, 27L, 97L, 10L, 48L, 217L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-155L), groups = structure(list(Batch.x = c("", "AA", "BA", 
"BN", "NC", "KJ", "UY", "IU", "PK", "LD", "OF", "PE", 
"HX", "ZT", "ZZ", "XA", "PV", NA), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2:4, 5:14, 15:24, 25:34, 35:44, 45:54, 55:64, 65:74, 
    75:84, 85:94, 95:104, 105:114, 115:124, 125:134, 135:144, 
    145:154, 155L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**My Code:**

```
Pivot_df <- Dataframe %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Batch.y, values_from = N)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1st value in `Batch.y` is empty, tibbles cannot have empty column names hence you get the error. Rename the empty values to some value and you can reshape the data then.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Dataframe %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Batch.y = replace(Batch.y, Batch.y == '', 'None')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Batch.y, values_from = N)
```